# Show that $\frac12\|A\|_2\leq \sup_{\|u\|_2=1}|u^HAu|$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms

Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, show that
$$\frac12\|A\|_2\leq \sup_{\|u\|_2=1}|u^HAu|,$$
where $\|A\|_2$ is the 2-norm of $A$.

Comment: Are you sure isn't $1/n$ instead of $1/2$? Consider $n>4$ and $A$ the identity matrix.

Comment: @azif00 Note that in this context, the $2$-norm might refer to the induced $2$-norm (AKA spectral norm) as opposed to the Frobenius norm.

Comment: @BenGrossmann That's makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**1.)**  all vectors are constrained to have a length (2 norm) of one
**2.)** for notational simplicity, I assume WLOG that the Hermitian part of $A$  has a maximal singular value at least as large as the maximal singular value of the skew-hermitian part of $A$.  (If this wasn't true, the only alteration would be on the 3rd to last line, we'd change the plus sign to a minus sign)

$\Big \Vert A \Big \Vert_2$
$= \Big \Vert \frac{1}{2}\big(A+A^*\big) + \frac{1}{2}\big(A-A^*\big) \Big \Vert_2 $
$\leq \frac{1}{2}\Big \Vert \big(A+A^*\big)\Big\Vert_2 + \frac{1}{2}\Big\Vert \big(A-A^*\big) \Big \Vert_2 $
$= \max_{x} \frac{1}{2}\Big\{\Big \vert \mathbf x^*\big(A+A^*\big)\mathbf x\Big \vert\Big\}  + \max_{y} \frac{1}{2}\Big\{\Big \vert \mathbf y^*\big(A-A^*\big)\mathbf y\Big \vert\Big\} $
$\leq 2 \cdot \max_{x} \frac{1}{2}\Big\{\Big \vert \mathbf x^*\big(A+A^*\big)\mathbf x\Big \vert\Big\}   $
$\leq 2 \cdot \max_{x} \frac{1}{2}\Big\{\Big \vert \mathbf x^*\big(A+A^*\big)\mathbf x +\mathbf x^*\big(A-A^*\big)\mathbf x\Big \vert\Big\}   $
$= 2 \cdot \max_{x} \Big \vert \mathbf x^*A\mathbf x \Big \vert  $

justifications:
sub-additivity of operator 2 norm, normal matrices have maximal singular values given by modulus of a quadratic form.  Finally recall that a quadratic Hermitian form is purely real and a quadratic skew-hermitian form is purely imaginary